# laravel - after removing updated_at and created_at columns from database laravel tries to insert into them

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I have deleted created_at and updated_at from database but laravel tries to insert into these columns however I have deleted both from database and code in controller. I think something is cached. BTW I don't want to use `public $timestamps = false` in model because it seems they are extra and unneeded.

Comment: Did you remove them from the migrations?

Comment: yes! removed from db, migration, controller!

Answer (score 3):

Well, in fact you need to set:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

and it's not extra and unneeded because by default it's assumed models have timestamps (and in fact it's very reasonable to keep them almost in all tables).

Timestamps are used in process of saving record:

```
if ($this->usesTimestamps()) {
    $this->updateTimestamps();
}
```

so there is no other shorter way when you are using Eloquent to set this property to false when you don't have those columns in table.

Comment: so you mean each table needs those two columns and they are required?? i'm not sure! because i have several tables not having these two and are working properly!

Comment: If you use Eloquent for saving all tables should have timestamps by default except pivot tables. But if you are using for example query builder they are not needed.

Comment: I don't know what pivot table is. What I know is I have used Eloquent and none of them need it!

Comment: So why you are asking on SO if you know that Eloquent doesn't need them? As I said by default Eloquent will always try to set created_at and updated_at columns if you don't set timestamps to false